# Hide a button when cilick outsite of the button or div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a button hide when outside of the button click .

Html :

```html
<div style="background:#FF0000;">

  <div style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; padding:50px;">

    <button name="Submit" type="submit" class="social_button_area_post" title=" Share Your Flow ">
      <i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i> Video
    </button>

    <button name="Submit" type="submit" class="social_button_area_post" title=" Share Your Flow " id="hidethisbutton">
      <i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i> Post
    </button>

    <button name="Submit" type="submit" class="social_button_area_post" title=" Share Your Flow ">
      <i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i> Photo
    </button>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: _What you want exactly?_

Comment: No I need out side of button click than the button hide only . Firstly , See the div and button after that when I click the div the button will hide. Thanks Sir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).click(function() {
    $("#hidethisbutton").hide();
  })

  $("#hidethisbutton").click(function() {
    return false;
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background:#FF0000;">

  <div style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; padding:50px;">

    <button name="Submit" type="submit" class="social_button_area_post" title=" Share Your Flow ">
      <i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i> Video
    </button>

    <button name="Submit" type="submit" class="social_button_area_post" title=" Share Your Flow " id="hidethisbutton">
      <i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i> Post
    </button>

    <button name="Submit" type="submit" class="social_button_area_post" title=" Share Your Flow ">
      <i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i> Photo
    </button>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want to hide this button using id like button id = test1

Comment: No sir when I click outside of the div than the other button also hide :( I will update my quesiton again thanks

Comment: hide the post button only other two button not hide

Comment: @SaifulIslamSagor hey now check. I didnt understand what you mean by hide the post button only other two button not hide

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var button = $('button');

  if (!button.is(e.target)) {
    button.hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:250px; width:250px; background:#FF0000;">

  <div style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; padding:50px;">

    <button name="Submit" type="submit" class="social_button_area_post" title=" Share Your Flow ">
      <i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i> Post
    </button>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` to the button. Instead of id `class` will also work fine.
Use jquery [**visible-selector**](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to find if the element is visible

```
 $("body").on('click', function() {
      if ($("#social_button_area_post").is(':visible')) {
        $("#social_button_area_post").hide()
      }
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/tw6bjhh9/1/)

Comment: No I need out side of button click than the button hide only . Firstly , See the div and button after that when I click the div the button will hide. Thanks Sir